# What can I do to fix 'spawn Winappdriver.exe ENOENT' error in WebdriverIo's sample file?

Tags: webdriver-io

node:events:491
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: spawn c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Application Driver\WinAppDriver.exe ENOENT

Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:

facing these error when running WebdriverIo's sample file first time on my machine.

Comment: Please further clarify your problem, and include a reproducible code example. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I installed WinappDriver on my machine using msi file. winappDriver was missing from my machine due to that these error occured